# Timing when looking for my first degree-related job

Tags: job-search, student, first-job

My situation is similar to [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/519/19366), but with some differences:

I would be in my last degree year but I took a grant to study abroad. This year while abroad I've done an internship at the university (it is not yet finished, but it will end before the summer). To make it easier for me to learn the language of the country, I am taking fewer classes, and when I go back to my home university I will study another semester and do the bachelor's thesis. Because of this, my graduation date will be a year later.

I've already started looking for a job, not necessarily in my home country. I have had contact with a company abroad that **seems** interested in me (I didn't have any interview - I contacted them via Facebook first and then they requested I make an official application.).

My doubts come from the semester I still need to do, which would end in February. I don't want to leave my degree unfinished, and they showed that they were not in a hurry (they would "allow me time" to learn a needed skill for the position). But there are still 9 months until I would be free of the university to work. (The bachelor's thesis should be delivered in June so until then I will not be officially graduated.)

It seems to me quite early to start, but at the same time I don't find any reason to wait to look for a job (as it seems to be supported [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/6532/19366)). Should I wait until I start the course again in September? If this offer goes on, how I should deal with the interview during the semester?

Comment: Can you choose a topic for the thesis that is related to the company's business? In computer science some of the best last year projects which I supervised, were done by students working part or full-time and doing work that was a good topic for a thesis.

Comment: Well this might be possible to arrange something. I am also moving towards informatics, but I don't know if it will be welcome from my university. But it is an idea I didn't consider thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llopis- First, good on you for seeing opportunity, and seeking it out.  Second, good on you for wanting to finish your degree. It shows that you are willing to finish things, even if it is complicated.  I don't know the work situation in the particular countries you are discussing, but it appears that you have several options.

As greenfingers says, you may be able to tailor you thesis to the kind of work you want to do.  Here in the US, it is not uncommon for people to work while finishing school, and if you can find related work to what you are studying so much the better.

On the other hand, none of this job related stuff is guaranteed, and no matter how hard you try, you can't force the other side to hire you, and you have no control over the work that they will give you if they do.  Sometimes things magically work out well, and sometimes the chasing of things ahead of the curve can be a lot of emotional energy expended for naught.

If you do interview, you need to be honest about the fact that you intend to finish your degree, and what amount of time in your home country this will require.  You may not have to tell ALL of the detail, but you need to at least be honest and up front about the fact that there will be an amount of time that is needed to do that.

Best of luck with whatever happens.  You are thinking clearly, and are asking good questions.

Comment: Well, I don't have several jobs positions listed, that is why I didn't let this one pass. And about keep seeking any advice? Thanks!